# How does Pyspark decides data type of a column automatically when inferschema is set to True, What happens in the background

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, bigdata

According to documentation,

> inferSchema: automatically infers column types. It requires one extra
> pass over the data and is false by default

alright, I understood that spark will read the CSV to determine the data type and assigns accordingly.

I am curious to know what is happening in the background.

1. Does spark scans whole csv?
2. if it scans only a sample data, then how many rows will it scan?
3. How does spark conclude that so and so column is of a particular datatype and assigns it on inferSchema = true?

Can someone help me to understand it better or share some links!

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering some of your questions

1. By default yes but sampling ratio was introduced in new version where you can define the fraction of values which need to be scanned to infer schema (default is 1)
2. By default all rows as it mentions it will need one extra pass over data
3. it parses it each as integer, long, double, bool and finally string or exception if parsing fails and gives the final schema you can read an early version of code [here](https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/databricks/spark/csv/util/InferSchema.scala)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The points 1 and 2 are confusing. Can you please explain further. In the 1st point you mentioned sampling was introduced but the default value is 1. It means 1 row in each column? The 2nd says, by default all rows. Let us say I have 5 columns and 20000 rows, considering this can you please explain points 1 and 2.

Comment: Lets say your file has 1000 rows if you just use inferschema it will run code mentioned in point 3 over all 1000 rows which as written in point 2 is extra read of whole data, now if you want to limit it you can define sampling ratio as 0.5 in which case it should ideally run over only 500 rows

Comment: I appreciate your patience in explaining the things.  I am able to imagine the backend process now. Thank you.

Comment: You can upvote/accept the answer if your query is resolved by this discussion